# Vimwiki override default vim command <c-i> for "jump forward in jump list", how to re-map it to other key?

Tags: vim, keymapping

After installed Vimwiki, i found the default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is now mapped to command: VimwikiNextLink. And I have no way to jump forward in jump list anymore. Before this I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to jump back, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to jump forward in history.

Since so many people are using Vimwiki, does anyone had same issure? Is there a way to re-map the vim jump forward/backward function to e.g. F7/F8 key?

(I tried to find the vim command name for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then I can re-map it, the command name I thought could be e.g. ":jumpForward", but it turns out it doesn't look like there is a command name for it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all covered by the [fine documentation](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt#L259), and works the same for almost all plugins: Override the mapping *before* the plugin is sourced, e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <Leader>wn <Plug>VimwikiNextLink
```

PS: `<C-i>` is the same as `<Tab>`.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, for the quick and clear answer! Problem solved:)